# Can't use List in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

I would like to share my problem with you.
I can't use two List in a function but when a remove a List the program success.
My Code :

```
    com.poly.dao.ProductDao dao;
    com.poly.dao.CategoryDAO dao2;
    ServletContext app;
    @RequestMapping("/product/index")
    public String index(Model model) {
        com.poly.entity.Product item = new Product();
        model.addAttribute("item",item);
        List<Category> cate = dao2.findAll();
        List<Product> items = dao.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("items",items);
        model.addAttribute("cate",cate);
        
        return("admin/product/admin-add-product");
    }
```

When I remove a `List<Category> cate = dao2.findAll();` the program run but when I add this the program notices erro : `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.poly.dao.CategoryDAO.findAll()" because "this.dao2" is null`

I don't understand this erro. Anyone help my pls thanksss

Comment: read the error message: "this.dao2" is null. check your CategoryDAO class. repository or service or component annotation missing in this class

Comment: The most likely cause is that dao2 is itself null, which is probably caused by the way that you are inject your dependecies. Can you share how you define your dao?

Comment: Additional to the above you may also be missing @Autowired for dao2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh i found a solution for my code
I forgot write `@Autowired` above dao and dao2.
This is a solution for code.